# How can I show a dialog and capture the response

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void ShowIterationSelection()
{
    IterationForm iterationForm = new IterationForm(lblProjectID.Text);
    iterationForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

When I show the dialog it displays a list of iterations associated with the project using the ProjectID:

```
public partial class IterationForm : Form
{
    public IterationForm(string projectID)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadIterationsForProject(projectID);
    }

    private void LoadIterationsForProject(string projectID)
    {
        IterationRepository iterationRepo = new IterationRepository();
        Int64 ID = Convert.ToInt64(projectID);
        dgvIterations.DataSource = iterationRepo.FindAllIterations().Where(i => i.IDProject == ID).Select(i => new { Codigo = i.ID, Descripcion = i.Description, Inicio = i.StartDate, Fin = i.EndDate });
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I capture the selected value from the datagrid view and pass it my calling form to open another form with the select IterationID?

Thanks for the help.

So maybe something like:

```
private void ShowIterationSelection()
{
    IterationForm iterationForm = new IterationForm(lblProjectID.Text);
    var result = iterationForm.ShowDialog();
    showTheThing(result); //this uses the iterationID
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a public property on the iteration form that you can access from your main form.

```
public partial class IterationForm : Form
{ 
    // set this to the selected object (change to w/e type you need)
    public object SelectedObject{get; private set;}
    public IterationForm(string projectID)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadIterationsForProject(projectID);
    }

    private void LoadIterationsForProject(string projectID)
    {
        IterationRepository iterationRepo = new IterationRepository();
        Int64 ID = Convert.ToInt64(projectID);
        dgvIterations.DataSource = iterationRepo.FindAllIterations().Where(i => i.IDProject == ID).Select(i => new { Codigo = i.ID, Descripcion = i.Description, Inicio = i.StartDate, Fin = i.EndDate });
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
private void ShowIterationSelection()
{
    IterationForm iterationForm = new IterationForm(lblProjectID.Text);
    var result = iterationForm.ShowDialog();
    showTheThing(iterationForm.SelectedObject); //this uses the iterationID
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the result from ShowDialog() is an enum of the type DialogResult.
usually you would test if the form shown has an DialogResult of "Ok".
you can set a Property in your Form that holds your result for example in the property "ResultProperty" if you want to read it after the form has closed use something like:

```
IterationForm iterationForm = new IterationForm(lblProjectID.Text);
if ( iterationForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok )
{
    // read result
    var result = iterationForm.ResultProperty
}
else
{
    // user has not clicked ok - do some other stuff here
}
```

in the form you have shown you can place an eventhandler on the button that the user should click in case of acceptance and add code like this:

```
private void Accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ResultProperty = someResult;
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;
    this.Close();
}
```

if the user has clicked the cancel button you would set the property like:

```
private void Decline_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by giving your IterationForm a property for the selected ID:

```
public int SelectedID { get; set; }
```

When your user selects a row from your datagrid, you'll need to set the selectedID property. I'll leave that bit up to you.

Now, add a handler for the `Closed` event of your IterationForm:

```
private void ShowIterationSelection()     
{     
    IterationForm iterationForm = new IterationForm(lblProjectID.Text);
    iterationForm.Closed += new EventHandler(iterationForm_Closed)
    iterationForm.ShowDialog();     
} 

void iterationForm_Closed (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IterationForm form = (IterationForm)sender;
    showTheThing(form.SelectedID);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog()` only returns a [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx).

But, what you could do is query iterationID as a public property on IterationForm when a successful DialogResult is received. Something like:

```
        var iterationForm = new IterationForm(lblProjectID.Text);

        if (iterationForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // do something with iterationForm.SelectedIterationId
        }
```